# Conversations tab in some chatroom is not displaying

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, conversation

I have originally posted this on [math.meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/conversations-tab-in-mathematics-chatroom-is-not-displaying), but I am reposting it here, since I guess this might improve the chance of this problem being addressed. Moreover, as another user found the same problem with another chatroom on another site, this seems to be SE network problem and therefore this meta might be a better place to aks it.

The problem with Mathematics chatroom persists at least a few days.

When I go to the [information page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) about the chatroom called Mathematics and click on the [conversations tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics?tab=conversations), I am directed to [this error page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/info/36/mathematics) instead of begin shown all bookmarked conversations.

The other tabs on the information page are working fine for me.

At Mad Scientist pointed out in [his comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/conversations-tab-in-mathematics-chatroom-is-not-displaying#comment35289_9646), there is the same problem with [The Bridge chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now. There was an edge case in getting the "conversation ended" time where we ended up with an unexpected null value.